# Cannot display all the data of the same session user in PHP

Tags: php

The problem is when I start a session and I want to display all the data of the current session user is that only one data is fetch from the database. But when I put the session_start along with the table, I cannot access the echo username.

```
<?php  
session_start();  
if(!isset($_SESSION["uname"]))
{
 header("location:userdash.php");

}else{

                include('db.php');
                $sql ="Select * from poolreservation where uname ='".$_SESSION['uname']."'";
                $re = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($re))
                {   
                    $id = $row['id'];
                    $resortname = $row['resortname'];
                    $hourstay = $row['hourstay'];
                    $addon = $row['add on'];
                    $cin = $row['cin'];

                }
}


?> 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Reservation History</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="text/css" href="image/icon/history.png">
</head>
<body>

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="card text-center mt-2">
            <div class="card-header success-color mt-5">
              RESERVATION HISTORY
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
              <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th class="text-info">#</th>
                      <th class="text-warning">Name of resort</th>
                      <th class="text-warning">Hour of stay</th>
                      <th class="text-warning">Add-on</th>
                      <th class="text-warning">Date</th>
                    </tr>
                   </thead>
                   <tbody>
                        <th><?php echo $id; ?> </th>     
                        <th><?php echo $resortname; ?> </th>     
                        <th><?php echo $hourstay; ?> </th>
                        <th><?php echo $addon; ?> </th>     
                        <th><?php echo $cin; ?> </th>     
                   </tbody>
                </table>
```

I expect that it displays all of his/her data, I'm working on a transaction history btw.

Comment: Try initialising the variables after the include used to echo the user details like $id, $resortname and so on.

Comment: i put the <session> in between the <tbody>  </tbody> but the now the problem is that i cannot  display his/her name on the top of navbar.

Comment: i want to use double session_start; but it is not possible.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: (current)

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\proj\softeng\transhistory.php on line 39